# Views with taxonomy contextual filter not working in Russian language in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, transliteration

I have a `View` which works perfectly in English. 
It has a `contextual filter`, with options 
Content: Has `taxonomy term` ID , 
filters by taxonomy term with term name converted to term Id.

But when I put in the URL the term in Russian, Раздел, it does not show the content. 
When I check the SQL, to my surprise and dismay, this is what I find: `search_index.word = 'razdel'`.

Clearly there has been a transliteration. Maybe this is why it does not work. I do not really what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the collation of your fields and tables in database, try to check to see if all the tables collation is set to `utf8_general_ci`

you can google to find an script to bulk update your tables and or fields collation

Comment: Yes, the collation was right. The problem was that I preprocessed the data coming from the URL, and I had missed the following line of code in the return of the function: $taxonomy = urldecode($taxonomy); Later I did a return of $taxonomy. Still, as the View admin is not intercepted by this function, I cannot understand the problem with the transliteration, it is very strange. So I have the situation that the site is working fine (with that correction), but when I edit the View and try to replicate the same behaviour in the View display, I got empty results and that strange transliteration. Ma

Comment: Also about the views part, there may be a table left for views still having the same problem, try to check your whole database and make sure, otherwise there must be something wrong with your views